# Joining Master table and two fact tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Iam facing problem during joining of the data. i have tables as follows

Table1

```
ID  AMT Product
1   10   P1
2   20   P1
3   30   P2
4   40   P2
5   10   P3
```

Table2

```
ID1  AMT1
1   10
1   20
1   30
2   20
3   10
```

Table3

```
ID3 AMT3
1   20
1   40
2   50
5   20
```

Table 1 is mater table and table 2 and 3 are fact tables.
After joining master and fact table using below query i got out put [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukKLL.png) 
see attachment. i used following query to join the tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Table_1] a 
left join [dbo].[Table_2] b on a.ID=b.ID1 
Left Join [dbo].[Table_3] c on b.ID1=c.ID2
```

I want to join all 3 tables,after joining when aggregating AMT1 data at Product Level i need following output

```
Product Amt1
P1       80
P2       10
```

Can some one guide me how to do this.

### Thanks

Revathi

Comment: Where are you getting the 80 and 10 values for P1 and P2?  Is this an average sum for Amt1 and Amt2?  I doubt that is the case, but at this point, we have to guess what you are trying to do

Comment: If you have a formula that you are using to arrive at these numbers, please include it in your question

Comment: It is an aggregation sum at Product level.

Comment: So, for each P1, P2, etc. you want the sum of Amt1 and Amt2 in all rows?

Comment: Yes correct i need sum of Amt1 and Amt2 in all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion and another look at the data, I understand what you are looking for and what the problem is.  The AMT1 and AMT2 values will be duplicated if there are multiple unique combinations of them.  The solution below may not be the most efficient, but it uses a [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to do each of the joins separately, with a null value for the AMT not included in that part of the query:

```
SELECT z.Product, SUM(z.AMT1), SUM(z.AMT2) 
FROM (
    SELECT a.Product, b.AMT1, NULL as 'AMT2'
    FROM [dbo].[Table_1] a 
    left join [dbo].[Table_2] b on a.ID=b.ID1
UNION ALL
    SELECT a.Product, NULL as 'AMT1', b.AMT2
    FROM [dbo].[Table_1] a 
    left join [dbo].[Table_3] b on a.ID=b.ID2
) as 'z' 
GROUP BY z.Product;
```

NOTE: This also corrects a problem in the join logic.  The both of the two-column tables need to be joined based on the table including `Product` because you are grouping by the `Product` feild, rather than joining `Table_2` and `Table_3`

Comment: when i excute the above query i am getting P1 as 140,P2 as 10 but as per fact table 2 i should get AMT1 for P1 as 80 and P2 as 10.